# Why does AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient deadlock in C# Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I have used the **aws-samples** example named a**ws-cognito-dot-net-desktop-app** in C# and WPF in a Windows PC application:

[aws-cognito-dot-net-desktop-app](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-dot-net-desktop-app)

It works very well and correctly registers the user in Cognito.

**Now, I'm using the same code for an Android application with C#.**

To register a user, do the following:

```c
bool success = await helper.SignUpUser(etUserName.Text, etPasswordUser.Text, etEmailUser.Text, etPhoneUser.Text);
```

SignUpUser is as follows:

```c
internal async Task <bool> SignUpUser (string username, string password, string email, string phonenumber)
{

   Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider =
                     new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new 
   Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials());

   SignUpRequest signUpRequest = new SignUpRequest();

   ....
}
```

But in this part, when it comes to creating provider, the code freezes:

[image: deadlock]

No exception or some other type of error occurs.

Is there a way to find out with Visual Studio what is happening?

Any comment or suggestion is welcome.

**UPDATE**

The way I call SignUpUser is like this:

```c
private async void clickCreateUser(object o, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   try
   {

      CognitoHelper helper = new CognitoHelper();
      bool success = await helper.SignUpUser(etUserName.Text, etPasswordUser.Text, etEmailUser.Text, etPhoneUser.Text);
      ...

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Error: " + ex.Message, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Long).Show();
   }
}
```

**UPDATE2**

I got an example for Xamarin. Forms of this link:

[xamarinforms-awscognito](https://github.com/Pietervdw/xamarinforms-awscognito)

When reviewing the code and seeing how a provider is created, I changed the code to as follows:

```c
Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(/*new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials()*/new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

Now the code doesn't freeze and goes to the next line:

[image]

I need to keep going through the rest of the code to determine other possible issues

Comment: How do you call SignUpUser or the step above that? Do you call it with `Wait` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` anywhere?

Comment: I use a click event of a button asynchronously, I updated the question to put more details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the AWS region that is being used, as follows:

```c
Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.YourRegionAWS);
```

Comment: Consider marking it as answer to help others who're facing the same problem.